# Zend Server enable IPv6?

Tags: zend-server

I'm using Zend server with Apache2. My PHP version is 5.3.14

When I try to type my IPv6 (instead of localhost) in the browser I get nothing. After that I tried phpinfo() which I get IPv6 Support as disabled.

[image: phpinfo()]

I've been searching Zend Server forums and didn't get a result. So my question is how can I enable IPv6 Support?

Comment: You could start with this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ipv6-apache-configuration-tutorial/ . It's quite old, but there are all the basics up to apache. The point is - before PHP or Zend is able to get an IPv6 connection, all the layers below it need to be IPv6 enabled. Are they?

Also, as far as I can see, switching on IPv6 in PHP seems to be a *compile time* affair (you'll need to google around for that - I haven't come up with anything conclusive). In which case the question would be "how do I compile PHP with IPv6 support?".

Comment: Also, if you can't make enough progress, then there's always the possibility to add a proxy in front of apache/php/zend like nginx/varnish/haproxy or the like, that picks up the IPv6 traffic and forwards it as IPv4 to your stack.

Comment: I grew tired of it and switched to XAMPP